# Select inside a select using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, asp.net-core

Friends,

I'm trying to select a collection inside of my ViewModel, but i think i'm doing it in the wrong way, because my endpoint enters in a infinite loop when i keep the subselect in the query.

```
var products = 
    await _context.product
    .Select(prod => new ProductViewModel() {
        id = prod.id,
        name = prod.name,
        description = prod.description,
        rating = prod.rating,
        price = prod.price,
        photos = _context.product_photo
        .Where(photo => photo.product_id == prod.id)
        .Select(photo => new ProductPhotoViewModel()
        {
            product_id = photo.product_id,
            path = photo.path
        }).ToList()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

The `Where()` inside subselect it is just a failed attempt to make it work. I decided to keep it on the question just to say 'I already try it too, but didn't work'

How can i subselect a collection? If this collection have another subcollection, it is possible to select it too?

**EDIT:**

`ProductViewModel:`

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    //Product
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int? rating { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    //Product photo
    public List<ProductPhotoViewModel> photos;
}
```

`ProductPhotoViewModel:`

```
public class ProductPhotoViewModel
{
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: don't you have key relationship defined in the model??

Comment: Yes, i have. i just not put it in the question, but in the `Where()` you can see it. By the way, i have edited the question.

Comment: then use the entity framework to load the related entity and convert into the view-model. Don't loop through photos for every product.

Comment: How do you know it's in an infinite loop? It looks like you're trying to load the entirety of your `product` table and a lot of the `product_photo` table into your `products` variable. That's not a scalable way to go about things.

Comment: If i remove the subselect, the request finishes in a half second. I just have 2 photos in my developer dabatase, so i think if the request takes more than ten minutes (currently, it do), it can spend a lot of time (maybe infinite time) to get finished.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your `ProductPhotoViewModel` class?

Comment: @JLRishe Of course, my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting queries is often a bad idea since the underlying data reader may cause conflicts when you want to read a result while another result is currently being read.

Without knowing too much about your data setup, I would recommend you to split this up completely. So you first query the products, and then you query all the photos and merge those into the view models:

```
// load all products
var products = await _context.product
        .Select(prod => new ProductViewModel() {
            id = prod.id,
            name = prod.name,
            description = prod.description,
            rating = prod.rating,
            price = prod.price,
        })
        .ToListAsync();

// find all product photos
var productIds = products.Select(p => p.id).Distinct().ToList();
var photos = await _context.product_photo
        .Where(photo => productIds.Contains(photo.product_id))
        .Select(photo => new ProductPhotoViewModel()
        {
            product_id = photo.product_id,
            path = photo.path
        })
        .ToListAsync();

// match photos to products
foreach (var product in products)
{
    product.photos = photos.Where(photo => product_id == product.id).ToList();
}
```